# Differentiation of multiple variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Could someone please explain how the solution was obtained to the following differential expression?

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d(VK)}{dK} = V + K\frac{d(V)}{dK}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the product rule,

$$\frac{d(VK)}{dK} = V\frac{dK}{dK} + K\frac{dV}{dK} = V + K\frac{dV}{dK}$$

as $\frac{dK}{dK}=1$.